# Alert displays twice after setting its state variable only once

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to have this button run a certain command and if it fails, I want it to display an `Alert` saying it failed. It does this fine except when the alert displays, it displays twice but I only set it once.

Here are the two state variables I use to display the alert:

```swift
@State private var alert = false
@State private var alertView = Alert(
    title: Text("Well Hello There"),
    message: Text("You probably shouldn't be seeing this alert but if you are, hello there! (This is a bug)")
)
```

And here's my button:

```swift
Button(action: {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        if let command = action.command {
            let error = Connection.shared.run(command: command)
            if error != nil {
                self.alertView = Alert(
                    title: Text("Failed to Run Action"),
                    message: Text("An error occurred while attempting to \(action.label).")
                )
                print("Displaying alert") // This only gets printed once
                self.alert = true
            }
        }
    }
}) {
    Text(action.label)
}.alert(isPresented: self.$alert) {
    self.alertView
}
```

Comment: Instead of `self.alertView = Alert` just return alert in-place, and you wan't see it twice.

Comment: @Asperi I need to use `alertView` instead of just having the `Alert` in the `.alert` function because I need to have multiple different alerts. I left the code for the other alerts out though to keep the code block simple.

Comment: what iOS are u testing? in simulator 13.2 it looked ok for me....but i had to change a bit, because action was not defined...

Comment: @Chris I'm actually using macOS.

Comment: Any news on this? I'm having the exact problem.

Comment: @ArmanMomeni Unfortunately not, I never ended up figuring it out. It might be worth opening a new question for.

Comment: Don't know if that will solve the issue but all UI code should be executed on the main thread

Answer (score 2):

It's my experience running on macOS. That might be different from yours.

I had a routine in Alert() closure that would trigger a UI refresh because it alters a state variable. It happened the refresh occurred before "isPresent" being toggled automatically by closing the alert presentation, so the view caught the "isPresent" again during the refresh. I can avoid this either by adding some delay to the routine or, in a safer way, hook the alert modifier to a view that is not affected by the refresh.

Comment: This was my case as well. Got it resolved by wrapping the logic that modified state in `DispatchQueue.main.async`

Answer (score 1):

Well I think I have found what the problem is, If you put the alert modifier inside a `forEach` it actually happens to trigger twice for some reason.
Just bring it out and it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

What if you set false to self.alert forcibly ?

```swift
.alert(isPresented: self.$alert) {
    self.alertView
}.onAppear{
    self.alert = false
 }
```

Comment: This worked for me