# SwiftUI Alert showing twice despite only setting its State variable once

Tags: arrays, swift, binding, alert

In my swiftUI MacOS app, I show an alert by setting a State variable bound to the alert to true. However after dismissing the alert, it displays again and I have to dismiss it again.

I did see the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59118091/swiftui-alert-displays-twice-after-setting-its-state-variable-only-once) with the same question but there didn't seem to be a conclusion.

Here is the alert:

```
.alert(isPresented: $showingCantDeleteInstanceAlert) {
    Alert(
        title: Text("Unable to delete instance \"\(instances[selectedInstanceIndex ?? 0].wrappedName)\""),
        message: Text("Can't have zero instances. Create a new instance to delete this one."),
        dismissButton: .default(Text("OK"))
    )
}
```

Here's the code that sets the State variable:

```
if instances.count <= 1 {
    showingCantDeleteInstanceAlert = true
    return
}
```

I even tried manually setting the variable to false when the alert is dismissed:

```
.alert(isPresented: $showingCantDeleteInstanceAlert) {
    Alert(
        title: Text("Unable to delete instance \"\(instances[selectedInstanceIndex ?? 0].wrappedName)\""),
        message: Text("Can't have zero instances. Create a new instance to delete this one."),
        dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")) {
            showingCantDeleteInstanceAlert = false
        }
    )
}
```

but the problem persists, the alert is still displayed twice...

Any ideas what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

I think I can see the issue

```
if instances.count <= 1 {
    showingCantDeleteInstanceAlert = true
    return
}
```

needs to be

```
if instances.isEmpty {
    showingCantDeleteInstanceAlert = true
    return
}
```

I shall explain, its fairly simple but I'll explain anyway, your doing `<=` which in this case is probably causing your issue.
So, to start with `instances.count` would be 0 then you present an alert and now `instances.count` is 1, when you perform the check `instances.count <= 1` its going to be true because that check is saying `if instances.count is less than or equal to 1 then proceed` because instances.count is equal to 1.

Also, make sure you're setting `showingCantDeleteInstanceAlert` back to false

Comment: If this is the case then I would suggest using `isEmpty` instead

Comment: I have updated my answer. isEmpty is much better

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately this didn't solve it, isEmpty didn't work because I need to make sure there are never 0 instances, so this code runs before I delete an instance. It needs to run if there is only 1 instance, since I don't want it to be deleted in that case. Additionally, the function which trigger the alert is only being run once, I can verify that by putting a print() underneath `showingCantDeleteInstanceAlert = true`. It definitely seems to be a problem with the alert and not the code that triggers it.